# Initializing a specific index in string array with null

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

I have string `a[]=new a[4];`

How to initialize `a[0] = null;`?

I need to have the following values in my array: `a,null,b,null`

I do not want to initialize when I declare my string array itself.

Answer (score 4):

You're using `a` to mean three different things - the array variable, a type, and a value within the array. That's clearly not going to work. However, you can do this:

```
String a = "hello";
String b = "there";

String[] array = { a, null, b, null };
```

or if you want to separate the declaration and initialization:

```
String[] array;

...

array = new String[] { a, null, b, null };
```

If you *just* create a new array, e.g.

```
String[] array = new String[4];
```

then all the element values will be null by default to start with, so you don't need to do anything else. You could do:

```
String[] array = new String[4];
array[0] = a;
array[2] = b;
```

If you *need* to set an element to null, you just do that in the obvious way:

```
array[0] = null;
```

Comment: Since the original question is marked with the tag "Java", the 'string' in your code snippets should be 'String'. :-)